# Change trialId in Google AI Platform hyperparameter tuning

Tags: gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-ai-platform, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I'm trying to follow this tutorial on hyperparameter tuning on AI Platform: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/hyperparameter-tuning-on-google-cloud-platform-is-now-faster-and-smarter.

My configuration yaml file looks like this:

```
trainingInput:
  hyperparameters:
    goal: MINIMIZE
    hyperparameterMetricTag: loss
    maxTrials: 4
    maxParallelTrials: 2
    params:
      - parameterName: learning_rate
        type: DISCRETE
        discreteValues:
        - 0.0005
        - 0.001
        - 0.0015
        - 0.002
```

The expected output:

```
  "completedTrialCount": "4",
  "trials": [
    {
      "trialId": "3",
      "hyperparameters": {
        "learning_rate": "2e-03"
      },
      "finalMetric": {
        "trainingStep": "123456",
        "objectiveValue": 0.123456
      },
    },
```

Is there any way to customize the `trialId` instead the defaults numeric values (e.g. 1,2,3,4...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to customize the `trialId` as it is dependent on the parameter `maxTrials` in your hyperparameter tuning config.

[maxTrials](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#hyperparameterspec) only accepts integers, so the assigned value to `trialId` will be a range from 1 to your defined `maxTrials`.

Also as mentioned in the [example in your post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/hyperparameter-tuning-on-google-cloud-platform-is-now-faster-and-smarter) where `maxTrials: 40` is set and it yields a json that shows `trialId: 35` which is within the range of `maxTrials`.

> This indicates that 40 trials have been completed, and the best so far
> is trial 35, which achieved an objective of 1.079 with the
> hyperparameter values of nembeds=18 and nnsize=32.

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to assign a name to the trialId? For example, ABC_1, should there be somewhere to customize that?

Comment: @HaAnTran It is not currently possible to customize trialId as explained in the answer. But if you'd like you can create a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) so the engineers might consider this feature moving forward.